# How do I determine and shut off an alarm that goes off?

Tags: notifications, alarm, iphone

I have an iPhone 7 Plus running 10.1.1. Everything works fine but I have a audible notice that goes off every morning at 8:00am. The problem is I don't know what it is from. I checked the clock app and I don't have any alarms set. I thought it was the Golden Days app, but even after removing it, the notice gots off. I have several items in OmniFocus that are due at 8:00am, but to my knowledge OmniFocus does not use audible notifications. I am stumped.

Any guidance on how to track down and shut off this daily notice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry that should be audible. It makes a notification sound.

Comment: have any alarm apps on your phone like alarmy? weather apps like poncho? games that want you to play again or remind you of a daily bonus at 8 am?

Comment: it would help if you include a video of your iPhone at 8am just before, during, and after the sound going off; please turn the screen on while the alarm sounds with the home button or raise-to-wake.

Comment: once you post the video to your question, just comment `@owlswipe` to let me know

Comment: also try changing your system time to 7:59 am right now and filming to speed up the process.

Comment: I set the time manually to 7:59am and waited until 8:00am an not alarms went off. I don't have alarmy or poncho or any active games. Any other ideas?

Comment: so it's a server-based app ringing

Comment: I guess just set the time back to real time, then wait till actual 8 am and film it for me. Again, film everything just before, during, and after the sound going off; please turn the screen on while the alarm sounds with the home button or raise-to-wake (not with the power button).

Answer (score 2):

My apologies to the community for the long delay in responding to this question. I finally figured out that it was the Reminders app that was going off each morning at 8:00am. Even though no reminders were showing up on the lock screen of my iPhone, the alarm went off dutifully.

The solution: turn off notification for Reminders in the Notification Center.